# Golang c-shared on linux - ld cannot find -ltest

Tags: gcc, go, cgo

I'm trying to follow the instructions in http://snowsyn.net/2016/09/11/creating-shared-libraries-in-go/

My project is somewhat simpler. The library has one test function with println. As the title says, I'm getting 'cannot find'.

I'm running Ubuntu zesty and go 1.7.4

ls -l

`roy@roy-desktop:~/go/src/c$ ls -l
total 2016
-rw-rw-r-- 1 roy roy      43 Dec 10 06:55 test.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 roy roy    1274 Dec 10 06:54 test.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 roy roy 2053664 Dec 10 06:54 test.so`

test.c

```
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    test();
}
```

lib.go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "C"


//export test
func test() {
    fmt.Println("test")
}

func main() {}
```

test.h and test.so were generated with: go build -o test.so -buildmode=c-shared test.go

invocation of gcc fails as follows:

```
roy@roy-desktop:~/go/src/c$ gcc -o test test.c -L. -ltest
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The original example uses clang but googling indicates the invocation should work for gcc as well.

### Post Solution

A couple of extra comments:

1. A function name in go `func test() {}` will appear in nm as `_test` but should be declared in C as `extern void test();`
2. For some reason, the invocation `go build -buildmode=c-shared` does not generate a header file on OSX but does on Linux.

Comment: Try renaming the file `libtest.so`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the difference between the go build commandline in the instructions you say
you are following:

```
go build -o libimgutil.so -buildmode=c-shared imgutil.go
            +++^^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

and your own go build command:

```
go build -o test.so -buildmode=c-shared test.go
            ^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^
```

Consider this difference in the light of [the documentation of the linker
option `-l | --library`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.27/ld/Options.html)

```
-l namespec
--library=namespec

Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of files to link.
                                            ^^^^^^^^
This option may be used any number of times. If namespec is of the form :filename,
                                                ^^^^^^^^                +^^^^^^^^
ld will search the library path for a file called filename, otherwise it will
                                                  ^^^^^^^^
search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a.
                                          +++^^^^^^^^++
On ... ELF and SunOS systems, ld will search a directory for a library called
libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a. (By convention,
+++^^^^^^^^+++                                 +++^^^^^^^^++
a .so extension indicates a shared library.) ...
```

This will show you that your go build command needs to be:

```
go build -o libtest.so -buildmode=c-shared test.go
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `gcc -o test test.c -L. -l:test.so` to link the library.